# Numeric value is not recognized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to execute a query like this and getting the numeric value not recognized error. The datatypes for the columns used are

```
Col1 - VARCHAR, 
Col2 - VARCHAR, 
Col3 - TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
```

This is my query

```
Select count( distinct ( 
                     case when Col1 > 100 
                     then concat(col2,cast(col3 as string))
                     else 0
end))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your CASE is returning a `string` and a `number` which are not the same types, so if you make the `0` into a string `'0'` that should work better.

A side note, you will still have a count of 1 for the all the values <= 100, which seems somewhat strange. Where-as if you used `null` instead of the 0 then it will not count, and will not have a type problem.

Answer (score 2):

your `Col1` is a `VARCHAR`, yet you are comparing it to a number. While snowflake does have an optimistic automatic type conversion (ie it will convert the string in `Col1` to a number), it might fail for one or more of the values. And as you don't catch these errors, your query will fail as a whole.

```
Select count( distinct ( 
                     case when try_to_number(Col1) > 100 
                     then concat(col2,cast(col3 as string))
                     else '0'
end))
```

[`try_no_number`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html) will try to convert the values of `Col1` to a number and return `null` when it fails. But it won't throw an error.

And also take into account what Simeon said. Ie the result of your `CASE` has different types. I don't know, how `DISTINCT` handles this, but I can imagine, that it decuces the type from the first value it sees, and if that is a number, it might try to convert all other elements to numbers as well, which can --depending on the values -- lead to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the error:

`Numeric value 'neverNull' is not recognized`

The error is complaining about an empty string, being inside of a numeric column or trying to insert.

To get around this, Try:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER(A.NUMERIC_FIELD_TYPE::VARCHAR) AS FIELD_TEST
FROM ABC AS A
```